Interpretation of coxPH model with and without splines for non-linearity
I am fitting Cox Proportional Hazard Models to investigate the impact of external, military support (my covariate) on the "risk" of a peace agreement (my event of interest) after civil war.
I expect that higher military support decreases the risk of a peace agreement. Before modeling, I plotted cumulative incidence functions to grasp an idea of what's happening in the data, and my expectation seems to be confirmed by the figure and the risk table below:
1]1
I set up the first basic cox model. I would interpret from this result that indeed, support significantly decreases the risk of cases transitioning from state 1 (fighting) to state 2 (peace agreement):
support_fit1 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, outcome_event) ~ avg_support_per_year,data = only_major_dyads_set, id = dyad_id, istate = istate)
summary(support_fit1)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, outcome_event) ~ avg_support_per_year, 
    data = only_major_dyads_set, id = dyad_id, istate = istate)

  n= 395, number of events= 212 

                                coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)  robust se      z Pr(>|z|)  
avg_support_per_year_1:2 -0.1203942  0.8865708  0.0452338  0.0469175 -2.566   0.0103 *
avg_support_per_year_1:3 -0.0004054  0.9995946  0.0220274  0.0218498 -0.019   0.9852  

Now, as I thought from the figure above, the effect might be non-linear, I first tested the proportional hazards assumption using cox.zph
> support_zp <- cox.zph(support_fit1)
> support_zp
                            chisq df    p
avg_support_per_year_1:2 0.03614  1 0.85
avg_support_per_year_1:3 0.00172  1 0.97
GLOBAL                    0.03786  2 0.98

Even though the results did not suggest it, I still implemented natural cubic splines with a knot at 12 months in a second model, to check for non-linear effects.
only_major_dyads_set <- only_major_dyads_set %>%
  mutate(time_spline_1 = ns(tstop, knots = 12)[, 1],
         time_spline_2 = ns(tstop, knots = 12)[, 2])

support_fit2 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, outcome_event) ~ avg_support_per_year +
                         avg_support_per_year:time_spline_1 + 
                         avg_support_per_year:time_spline_2,
                       data = only_major_dyads_set, id = dyad_id, istate = istate)

> summary(support_fit2)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, outcome_event) ~ avg_support_per_year + 
    avg_support_per_year:time_spline_1 + avg_support_per_year:time_spline_2, 
    data = only_major_dyads_set, id = dyad_id, istate = istate)

  n= 395, number of events= 212 

                                            coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z Pr(>|z|)    
avg_support_per_year_1:2                0.11671   1.12379  0.06016   0.06513  1.792   0.0731 .  
avg_support_per_year:time_spline_1_1:2 -1.60309   0.20127  0.40637   0.39979 -4.010 6.08e-05 ***
avg_support_per_year:time_spline_2_1:2 -0.50001   0.60652  1.03835   0.82466 -0.606   0.5443    
avg_support_per_year_1:3                0.25356   1.28860  0.02781   0.02691  9.421  < 2e-16 ***
avg_support_per_year:time_spline_1_1:3 -2.02472   0.13203  0.18918   0.26033 -7.778 7.39e-15 ***
avg_support_per_year:time_spline_2_1:3  0.04356   1.04452  0.30711   0.22598  0.193   0.8472

How would you interpret the results of this second model? My hunch is that the main effect of support is now only marginally significant but even it is positive now (so higher support makes a peace agreement more likely)? Does the significant, negative interaction with the first spline (2nd row) only tell me that the effect decreases over time? What puzzles me the most is how the effect of the first model seems to be reversed. Is it even advisable to implement splines, as cox.zph() above indicated no need? (However, AIC(support_fit1) = 1923.281, while AIC(support_fit2) = 1614.28).
Any insight on any of these aspects much appreciated!

This isn't a proper way to deal with potential proportional hazards violations. What you should do is to allow for a time-varying coefficient for your avg_support_per_year predictor, as in Section 4.2 of the R survival time-dependence vignette. Setting up a spline for the observed tstop values isn't appropriate. As tstop is an outcome value, you are using an outcome value to predict the outcome. That breaks the rule about not looking into the future, as explained in the linked vignette section.

Thanks, that already helps!
